# How to increase total simultaneous keypresses?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, keypress

I've been doing a bit of research as I'm having a problem in a game I developed where the app is only picking up a few key presses. The game is a chrome web store app built with HTML/CSS/JavaScript.

http://jsfiddle.net/gFcuU/

```
var keys = {};

$(document).keydown(function (e) {
keys[e.which] = true;

printKeys();
});

$(document).keyup(function (e) {
delete keys[e.which];

printKeys();
});

function printKeys() {
var html = '';
for (var i in keys) {
    if (!keys.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
    html += '<p>' + i + '</p>';
}
$('#out').html(html);
}
```

This is someone else's JSFiddle that shows the keys that are being pressed on your keyboard. I can only get a maximum of 6 at one time. I'm having complaints about my game from people who can't press more than 3 keys at once. I believe this is a keyboard limitation but **is there ANY work around at all?**

As you can imagine, if only 3 keys can be pressed at one time, this makes it difficult to play a multiplayer game that uses WASD for player 1, and IJKL for player 2 to move around at the same time.

Comment: You might find these articles helpful:  http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6669/how-do-i-remove-the-limit-on-pc-keyboard-button-presses  and   https://www.microsoft.com/appliedsciences/antighostingexplained.mspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array to hold key states

```
var keyStates = [ ];

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    keyStates.push( e.keyCode );
}, false);

document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    var pos = null;

    if( (pos = keyStates.indexOf( e.keyCode )) > -1 )
        keyStates.splice( pos, 1 );
}, false);
```

Comment: I understand how to hold keystates, its that there is a cap on how many keys the browser will pick up simultaneously. Anyway, it does seem to be a keyboard limitation (thanks to SimianAngel) http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6669/how-do-i-remove-the-limit-on-pc-keyboard-button-presses